# serial problem with python to arduino

Tags: serial, python

when i execute the python script, the arduino response but the code between the if(Serial.available()) not responding.

python script

```
 import  time, serial
 arduino = serial.Serial('COM7', 9600)
 time.sleep(2)
 while True:
    arduino.write(str(input("1")))                  # write position to serial port
    # and the pysthon script cant read the code below this line
    reachedPos = str(arduino.readline())            # read serial port for arduino echo
    data.append(reachedPos)
    arduino.close()
```

arduino script

```
 #include <Servo.h>
 Servo servo;
 int angle = 0;
 String in;
 int pos = 1;

void setup() {
 servo.attach(7);
 Serial.begin(9600);
 servo.write(0);

}


void loop() {
if(Serial.available())  // if data available in serial port
{
in = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
Serial.print(in);
pos = in.toInt();
  if(pos == 1){
if(angle == 0){
  servo.write(180);               
  delay(10);
  angle = 180;
  delay(1000);
}

if(angle == 180){
  servo.write(0);
  delay(10);
  angle = 0;
  delay(1000);
}}
}
}
```

What is the problem?
Te arduino code works fine

Comment: 1. You're reading up until a `\n`, but you're never sending a `\n` - so you end up receiving until a timeout. That consumes *everything* in the buffer. 2. You then look to see if there's something available. There isn't. You've consumed it all.

Comment: i have the same problem when i use Serial.read()

Comment: You mean you read everything, and then you look to see if something is available? Of course that will never work. You need to rethink your whole strategy.